# Visualizing layout key maps in xkb

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using

```
setxkbmap -query layout us,in -variant ,tam
```

to be able to enter tamil characters. I've not used it before, so I can't find the keys on the keyboard very easily. I've used

```
xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/microsoft - | xkbprint -color -o - - | ps2pdf - > out.pdf
```

to view a map of the geometry of the keyboard. But I'd like to be able to view the actual unicode symbols on the keys. I see things like `<AE00>` on the pdf.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing with `xkbprint` recently for viewing modified XKB geometries.

1. Generate a keymap file with `setxkbmap -print`.  Add whatever layout/variant/options you're interested in -- for your case you might use `-model microsoft -layout in -variant tam`.  The `-print` option shows what would be loaded with the given options but won't change your current settings.  You'll probably get nicer output generating one layout at a time rather than using `-layout us,in`.
2. Compile that keymap with `xkbcomp`.
3. Convert that to a ps/pdf: `xkbprint -label symbols foo.xkm - | ps2pdf - > foo.pdf`.

All together:

```
setxkbmap -model microsoft -layout in -variant tam -print | 
  xkbcomp - - | 
  xkbprint -label symbols -color - - | 
  ps2pdf - > foo.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [`xkbprint` man page](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xkbprint.1.html), it shows..

> -label type
>       Specifies the labels to be printed on keys; legal types are: none, name,code,symbols.

I therefore assume that this should do the trick for you:

```
xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/microsoft - | xkbprint -label symbols -color -o - - | ps2pdf - > out.pdf
```

Comment: It gives the following error: `Error:            XKM file "stdin" doesn't have symbols.                  Cannot label keys as requested. Exiting`

Comment: that `xkbcomp` command only compiles a geometry file, hence the missing symbols.

Answer (score 0):

From anwser from @quixotic , I would add step 0:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+latam+inet(evdev)"  };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
```

Then use instead (pay attention to single quotes) :

```
$ setxkbmap -model pc -layout latam -geometry 'pc(pc105)' -print ...
```

Again, pay attention to single quotes, otherwise result in
"Error: XKM file "stdin" doesn't have symbols"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/389748)

Comment: If this is an addition to another answer, then maybe it should be suggested as an edit to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the keyboard layout you want to visualize can be found/loaded by GNOME (LibXklavier), you can use the `gkbd-keyboard-display` application from `libgnomekbd`:

```
bash% gkbd-keyboard-display --layout us
```

Variants of a layout must be separated with a tab character:

```
bash% gkbd-keyboard-display --layout $'us\tdvorak'
```

[image: gkbd-keyboard-display visualizing the US (Dvorak) keyboard layout]

```
bash% gkbd-keyboard-display --layout $'in\ttam'
```

[image: gkbd-keyboard-display visualizing the Indian Tamil (InScript, with Arabic numerals) keyboard layout]