# Show keyboard layout on XFCE

Tags: keyboard, xfce

How to show the GUI of keyboard layout on XFCE? like Gmome or MATE (see the picture)

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197670/how-could-i-see-the-keyboard-layout-in-xfce).

Answer (score 3):

Xfce provides You with this option in `Settings => Keyboard` under `Layout` section. However it does not show any visualization, just a simple list.

If You want to have an icon on your panel, like in Windows, You can add **xfce4-xkb-plugin** widget. Here it is nicely explained: https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/selecting-different-keyboard-layouts-in-xfce/

Comment: The whole point is to get a visualization of the layout.

Comment: Sorry for misleading info - i thought, that settings changing would be what You really want. So exact answer for Your question would be:

*You can not*

For visualization/edition you can however install some additional software, such as:

https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor

Comment: Or use some terminal application like explained in this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348021/visualizing-layout-key-maps-in-xkb

Comment: Yeah the point here is that there is no simple overview to see how your layout translates to your physical device/s.  There are a billion or so permutations of layouts and what not.  It's quite nice to be able to glance at so you can figure out where certain punctuation lies etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've needed to add Keyboard Layouts.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this, too (recently switched to Manjaro XFCE). Fortunately, if `gkbd-keyboard-display` is installed in your system (it most often is), you can write a little bash 3-liner to call it up, showing the currently set keyboard layout:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
# Show current keyboard layout
layout=`setxkbmap -query | grep layout | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2`
variant=`setxkbmap -query | grep variant | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2`
gkbd-keyboard-display -l ${layout}$'\t'${variant}
```

I call mine `show-kbd` and you can put it into `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, for example. Here’s an example for my keyboard:
[image: show-kbd]